# SQL Selecting Max and Min Dates in Different Rows

Tags: sql, sql-server, date, max, min

Thanks for your time! For each user, I am looking to output a single column which contains their earliest effective date and latest end date, along with other columns from this and other tables (this stuff is consistent for each user). Below is the format for the input data.

```
User   Eff_Date     End_Date    Otherstuff...
----|-------------|------------|---------
001 | 20140101    | 20140106
001 | 20140107    | 99990101
002 | 20140201    | 20140305
002 | 20140306    | 20140319
002 | 20140320    | 99990101
003 | 20140401    | 20140402
004 | 20140501    | 20250901
```

This is basically what I would prefer as a result:

```
User   Eff_Date     End_Date    Otherstuff...
----|-------------|------------|---------
001 | 20140101    | 99990101
002 | 20140201    | 99990101
003 | 20140401    | 20140402
004 | 20140501    | 20250901
```

Here is what I tried:

```
SELECT DISTINCT M.user, T.mineffdate, T.maxenddate, A.otherstuff


FROM tbluser M
LEFT JOIN otherstuff A ON A.[user]=M.[user]
INNER JOIN (SELECT user, MAX(m.end_date) as maxenddate, MIN(m.eff_date) as mineffdate FROM tbluser M GROUP BY user) T ON T.user = M.user AND T.maxenddate = m.end_date AND T.mineffdate = M.eff_date
```

When I ran this, users like 003 and 004 above showed up alright, but users like 001 and 002 failed to show up at all.

I am fairly new to SQL, so I might be making a very basic mistake. Feel free to let me know if that is the case. Additionally, I have no control over the data source, so I cannot fix this at the source. The only reason I found about about this was by using SQL to output every user record and then using VBA to assemble the records. This is unfortunately not a long-term solution.

Please let me know if you need any more info, and I appreciate everything, a nudge in the right direction might be enough to help me solve this. Thank you again for your time!

Comment: What sql platform are you using?  Tag the post appropriately with MySQL, SQL Server.. etc.

Comment: Sorry, SQL-Server 2012.

Comment: Well, "otherstuff" is on the same line as either min date or max date. So which "otherstuff" do you want ? The one with min date, or the one with maxdate ? That's the problem you have with user 1 and 2 : min date is not on the same line as max date !

Comment: The otherstuff is attached to the user number; it will not change based on date.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

How about using windowing functions?

Try this:

```
Select distinct t.[user],
Min(t.eff_date) Over (Partition By [user]) as EffDate,
Max(t.End_Date) Over (Partition By [user]) as EndDate,
'Other' as [Other]
From tblUser t
```

EDIT: Although keep in mind if the dates are stored as strings MIN/MAX will work on the strings, not the dates.  May need to convert to `Date` if they're stored as strings.

Comment: This looks good. The problem with this is that I am getting duplicate entries, despite the fact that I selected distinct

Comment: @Wolves you can't get "exact duplicates" with disctinct. Your problem comes probably from your other joined datas, no ?

Comment: Raphael, you're right... the problem with duplicates is being caused by another column which was slightly different. I have removed it, and this solution seems to be working as intended so far...

Comment: Done, sorry about that!

Answer (score 0):

Try to use where `NOT EXISTS` clause, the example may not be exactly what you want, but showing the clause which may help you

```
SELECT M.user, M.Eff_Date, M.End_Date, M.otherstuff
FROM tbluser M
WHERE NOT EXISTS(
  SELECT * FROM tbluser N
  WHERE M.user=N.user AND (N.Eff_Date > M.Eff_Date OR N.Eff_Date = M.Eff_Date AND N.End_Date > M.End_Date)
)
```

Comment: Thanks, I tried this and it looks like it is going to work. I need to run an exact comparison between the SQL output and what I know is correct, but the WHERE NOT EXISTS seems to be exactly what I am looking for. Thank you very much!

Comment: But be careful that my example might have some problem, that it only exports the results both eff_date and eff_date is maximum.

Comment: If you want to take first maximum of eff_data and second maximum of enddat, you should take `WHERE M.user=N.user AND (N.Eff_Date > M.Eff_Date OR N.Eff_Date = M.Eff_Date AND N.End_Date > M.End_Date)` inside the subquery to set the priority, so that for a single user, it always exports a row.

Comment: @Raphaël Althaus I've fixed it.

Comment: But that doesn't return the right min eff_date for user 1 and 2 (well, for all users which don't have min and max date on the same row)

Comment: @Raphaël Althaus as my previous reply, I change the condition.

Answer (score 0):

this should work:

```
SELECT M.user, M.mineffdate, M.maxenddate, M.otherstuff, a.otherstuff
FROM (SELECT USER, MAX(m.end_date) as maxenddate, 
                   MIN(m.eff_date) as mineffdate,
                   MIN(otherstuff) AS minotherstuff
      from tbluser
      group by user) M
LEFT JOIN otherstuff A ON A.[user]=M.[user]
```

Comment: your subquery seems not having a from clause.

Comment: sorry, copy-paste issue :)

Answer (score 0):

This is my quick solution for the problem

```
WITH MinTable As(
SELECT [User],MIN(Eff_Date) Eff_Date  FROM Test GROUP BY [User]),
MaxTable As(
SELECT [User],Max(End_Date) End_Date FROM Test GROUP BY [User])
SELECT MinTable.[User], MinTable.Eff_Date, MaxTable.End_Date FROM MinTable INNER JOIN MaxTable ON MinTable.[User] = MaxTable.[User]
```

Try this.